# How can I determine whether my node is successfully connected to CarrIOTA Field?

Tags: iri-node

I installed and started the [CarrIOTA Field](http://field.carriota.com/) Node.js app on my full server yesterday. As is explained in the [GitHub instructions for the app](https://github.com/SemkoDev/field.cli) I configured it to run as an auto-started process using [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#saving-current-processes).

Now I would like to know whether it is actually behaving as expected and doing any work from the other nodes.

Looking at the log file does not give me much information. The last line in the log just says "IRI Online!" as shown below.

[image: CarrIOTA Field log lines]

Also trying to find my node in the graph shown at [field.carriota.com](http://field.carriota.com/) has turned out to be impossible.

How can I determine whether my node is successfully connected to CarrIOTA Field and receiving work from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is indeed a bit weird that your IRI goes down three times. That is something which you need to investigate. I can not answer that based on provided info.

I can however answer the second part. Just lookup (ctrl+f) your node by the name or id on the following [url](http://field.carriota.com/api/v1/graph). You can see your stats there. If you want to see it in the dashboard, you need to find it in the  graph. I know that is not very convenient. But after you find it, you can add it to your favourites by clicking the star. From then on checking your stats becomes easier because your node will get a nice pink color :-) in the graph. Then just click it and voila your stats will appear in the left bar.

Comment: nice! thank you:-) would you know how often the information at the url is refreshed? I mean, if I get my node to connect successfully, how soon should I be able to see it in that list?

Comment: i think it updates each minute at least. just refresh a couple of times and see whether your node pops ups when searching.